# error: unable to upgrade connection: container not found ("wordpress")

Tags: wordpress, kubernetes

My goal is to list environment variables in my wordpress pod

```
kubectl get pods

wordpress-77f45f895-lxh5t            1/1     Running            993        92d
wordpress-mysql-7d4fc77fdc-x4bfm     1/1     Running            87         92d
```

Although the pod is running

```
kubectl exec wordpress-77f45f895-lxh5t env
error: unable to upgrade connection: container not found ("wordpress")
```

If I try the other one

```
kubectl exec wordpress-mysql-7d4fc77fdc-x4bfm env
Unable to connect to the server: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
```

My services

```
wordpress                NodePort       10.102.29.45     <none>        80:31262/TCP     94d
wordpress-mysql          ClusterIP      None             <none>        3306/TCP         94d
```

Why is container not found?

Comment: First off, one must separate the command from the pod name by `--` (dash dash) in order to help the kubectl parser know that you didn't intend that `env` for _it_; second, `kubectl exec` (and `logs`) contact the `kubelet` on the Node directly, so you must be able to access the **Node**'s IP on port 10250 which you seemingly cannot for the Node that is hosting `wordpress-mysql`

Comment: What are the 993 and 87 numbers in the first snippet? Restart counts? Then it might be your pods are in crashloopbackoff state and don't stay running long enough for you to exec them

Answer (score 38, accepted):

by looking at your output, I think your containers are crashing. first pod crashed 993 times and the second one crashed 87 times. You can check logs of the containers/events of the pods

`kubectl logs {{podname}}`: for pod logs

`kubectl describe pod {{podname}}` for detailed description.

As suggested by @mdaniel in comment check for ports also.

Are you able to access application on nodePort?

Answer (score 2):

The problem may be that the container hasn't been started yet. Use

```
kubectl describe pod <podname>
```

to see if you can view a message such as:

```
Normal  Created                 19s   kubelet                  Created container container

Normal  Started                 17s   kubelet                  Started container container
```

The container will have been created and you should no longer see that error message.